# Does $G$ act 2-transitively on its Bruhat-Tits building?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, algebraic-groups, p-adic-groups, buildings

Let $k$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group over $k$. We consider the action of $G$ on its Bruhat-Tits building $X$.

**Question:** If $x,y,x',y'$ are vertices, all of the same type, and $d(x,y)=d(x',y')$, is there a $g\in G$ with $gx=x'$ and $gy=y'$?

Comment: What is the meaning of "the same type"? for instance $PGL_d(Q_p)$ and $SL_d(Q_p)$ acts on the same BT-building but don't have the same vertex orbits.

Comment: Assume for simplicity sake that the building is a simplicial complex. Then  it is labellable : if $\Delta$ is the standard simplex with vertex set $\{ 0,1,...,d\}$, $d={\rm dim}(X)$, there is a simplicial map $l$ : $X\rightarrow \Delta$ whose restriction to any chamber is an isomorphism. For a vertex $s$, its label $l(s)$ is sometimes called its type. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Remark. You can reduce your problem to an appartment.  Any pair of vertices are in a commun appartement and $G$ acts transitively on the appartments of $X$, so you may assume that $x$, $y$, $x'$, $y'$ all lie in some fixed apparment, and you can replace $G$ by the affine Weyl group.

Comment: The question seems to me to be about unravelling the definition of the Bruhat--Tits building associated to $G$. If it is defined as the building associated to the affine $BN$-pair of $G$, then the answer is straightforward by observing that 2-transitivity is the same as Weyl transitivity, i.e. that a chamber stabilizer $B$ acts transitively on each $w$-sphere. This is implied by the Bruhat decomposition $G=BWB$ associated to the $BN$-pair.  See Abramenko--Brown's "Buildings" chapter 6.2.1, especially 6.34 and 6.35, for a more detailled discussion.

Comment: I think @PaulBroussous just about has a counterexample.  Let $x = x'$.  Then the subset of the affine Weyl group fixing $x$ is just a finite Weyl group.  And that definitely does not act transitively on the set of pts in the apartment at a fixed distance from $x$, when that fixed distance is chosen appropriately.  E.g., $S_3$ does not act transitively on the set of 12 vertices at distance $\sqrt{7}$, in type $A_2$.

Comment: @marty I'd assume that this is about the Weyl distance, though...

Comment: I suspect confusion could be avoided by starting with the well-understood rank 1 case.    (In any case, the question concerns an *algebraic* group rather than a *Lie* group, even though semisimple groups over an algebraically closed field are essentially the same in both settings.)

Comment: @PaulBroussous -- I now have doubts about the idea of reducing to the affine Weyl group.  I don't think that's going to work, since there could be elements of G that send (x,y) to (x',y') without preserving the chosen apartment.  Something else will be needed, and I don't know whether the result is true.

Comment: @Guntram big thanks for pointing me to the notion of w-sphere etc. This question was originally about the Euclidean metric (i.e. the metric in the usual sense of metric), but I realize that the concept of Weyl distance which I didn't know before is enough for my purposes.

Comment: The question as it was originally intended stays unanswered though, due to Marty's objection. I'm not sure what the MO convention is (rather new here): should I change the question so that it's answered or leave it as it is?

Comment: I think the question should be left open... at least I'd like to think about it a bit more, because I don't know the answer.  I hope my first comment didn't prevent more people from thinking about it!

Comment: Ok then I leave it open. Of course I'm also still interested in the answer for the reason that I also thought about this question for some time...